# Extract elements with specific css class

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to develop an application using Rails 4.0.

At some point my application receives an html marked-up text from user (some sort of template) and it has to detect some placeholders which will be filled, later, with the data user provides in the future, for mass mailing. Each placeholder is contained inside an `<span>` tag with class attribute set to `dynamic`.

Here lies my question: What is the quickest way to extract these placeholder (text inside `span` tags) to create the list I need? Is there any kind of ruby library that could help me with that?

Comment: why should you extract the values from the raw html? If it's some sort of template, can't you create a form for the user and use the conventional way of retrieving information?

Comment: @Dr.Nefario, application has to extract them in order to create the form. In order to mark the placeholder, I've implemented a simple button in CKEditor, which changes the text attribute. User writes a template and  then submits whatever he or she has written. Then and only then I know how many placeholder he has marked, and where they are placed in the text. As far as my knowledge goes, it the definition of a causal system (no way around it). I could design it differently (requiring user to state his placeholders before hand), but it would be a pain in both our necks (to implement and to use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem to parse.

```ruby
doc.search('span.dynamic').each do |dynamic|
  puts dynamic.content
end
```

When `doc` is a variable who receives a `Nokogiri::HTML`. See this [wiki](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki) to get better examples.

Comment: Nice and easy solution. Thanks!